# Java 'for' loop with range

Tags: java, for-loop, range

I am working on a basic program (console).

The program should allow the user to enter in various marks, until the mark entered exceeds 100. At this point the program should display a histogram. Each star represents a student who achieved a module mark in the range shown.

This is an example of the output.

**0 - 29 xxx**

**30 - 39   xxxxx**

**40 - 69   xxxxxxx**

**70 - 100  xxxx**

20 students in total.

As the user enters each mark, there ought to be a counter that increases in value and print the total number of marks entered.

I want to make sure that the program is as efficient as possible but also understandable

**Code**

Working with @Dici on collabedit I have an amazing answer to my question:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] ranges  =  { 0,29,39,69,100 };
    int[] inRange = new int[ranges.length - 1];

    int mark;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Mark:");
        mark = sc.nextInt();           
        for (int j=1 ; j<ranges.length ; j++)
           if (ranges[j-1] <= mark && mark <= ranges[j]) {
               inRange[j-1]++;
               break;
           }
    } while (mark <= 100);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inRange));

    String s = "The number of students that have scored between %d and %d is: ";
    int k = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<ranges.length - 1 ; i++) {
      System.out.print(String.format(s,ranges[i] + k,ranges[i + 1]));   
        for (int r = 0; r<inRange[i] ; r++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
        k = 1;
    }

    sc.close();
```

Thank you again for your amazing help!

Comment: Ranges of what? Do you want to break the possible grade range into "buckets" (e.g. 0 - 29, 30 - 59, etc.) and keep a running count of the grades in each bucket?

Comment: You need to be much more specific. We aren't mind readers, concise and targeted questions are best. Are you asking about ranges for the marks for the student?

Comment: Can you use Java 8 ?

Comment: @Dici I am using the Java 8 JDK

Comment: Your code doesn’t make the slightest sense. Neither does your request to put ranges into it. Maybe you try to fix you code regarding whatever it is supposed to do *without* these mysterious ranges. Once it does something useful you may come back to the idea of putting ranges to it.

Comment: @Holger Well I am here to learn, that is why I posted this here. Comments like that aren't very helpful if you belittle my efforts. I more than understand that my approach is not correct and that it needs adjustment

Comment: @Niral Mehta: what approach? I see a bunch of random code that can’t be said to have errors as it doesn’t seem to have a goal that it could miss. Just go through your code and try to tell what each expression is supposed to do and why. Since you didn’t tell what you actually want to do your code has to do it. But it fails to tell it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we did it together on Collabedit, here is a working code for your question :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] ranges  =  { 0,29,39,69,100 };
        int[] inRange = new int[ranges.length - 1];

        int mark;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Mark:");
            mark = sc.nextInt();           
            for (int j=1 ; j<ranges.length ; j++)
               if (ranges[j-1] <= mark && mark <= ranges[j]) {
                   inRange[j-1]++;
                   break;
               }
        } while (mark <= 100);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inRange));

        String s = "The number of students that have scored between %d and %d is : ";
        int k = 0;
        for (int i=0 ; i<ranges.length - 1 ; i++) {
          System.out.print(String.format(s,ranges[i] + k,ranges[i + 1]));   
            for (int r = 0; r<inRange[i] ; r++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
            k = 1;
        }

        sc.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite understand this. Is this correct, this a list and through the list you've defined a range of 0 to 100 on the second line.

Then you've created both a maximum and minimum range value that can be altered only within the code. I'm not quite understanding the *i +29** on your fourth line. Could you explain the fifth line to me please?

Comment: Let's assume you have the input array `[3,25,17,88]`. What you want is to know how many items of this array are in each range you defined, is that right ?

Comment: Yeah that is right, so you would use the above code to sort the array into the appropriate range?

Comment: Each element of the list is a `Predicate` with a `test` method. `test(i)` returns `true` iff `min <= i <= max`. I guess you see how it can be useful

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me, so if I wanted to store values ad have the list sort them can I use the scanner outside of the list?

Comment: You keep talking about sorting but that was not your original question. Plus, I don't understand the last part of your comment

Comment: I want to take each user input and fit it into a range. i.e 3 falls in to the range 0 - 29. Once the user input is added to the range it will then increment some kind of counter by 1 as it belongs there

Comment: Is it possible to private message you? This is what I want but it would be better for me to show you what I mean with a link to what I am being asked to do

Comment: Let's chat here, you don't have enough reputation for chatting on SO : http://collabedit.com/v2n8y

Answer (score 0):

Quick suggestion: do not alter `marksInsp` inside the loop if that's your loop index.

Paulinho made the excellent suggestion of using the [modulo operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html). I'll extend that here to a map, since you didn't specify the upper mark limit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int currentMark, currentBucket;
    final int BUCKET_WIDTH = 30;
    Map<Integer, Integer> markRanges = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Marks: ");
        currentMark = input.nextInt();
        currentBucket = currentMark % BUCKET_WIDTH;
        if(markRanges.containsKey(currentBucket)) {

            // There's already an entry for this bucket
            markRanges.put(currentBucket, markRanges.get(currentBucket) + 1);
        } else {

            // If there isn't, make a new entry
            markRanges.put(currentBucket, 1);
        }

        // Print out grade buckets
        for(Integer j : markRanges.keySet) {
            System.out.println(String.format("There are %d students with scores between %d and %d", markRanges.get(j), j, j.intValue() + BUCKET_WIDTH - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the end of your code it says that the variable is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: @NiralMehta yeah; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Now that makes sense. If you have a number

```
  int mark = 3;
```

You can use an if statement

```
 if(mark <= 10){

      //do this

 }else if(mark <= 20){

     //do this

  }
```

You can also use a switch statement, however personal preference leads me to almost always use if statements.

If you want "buckets" you could use

```
  ArrayList<String> marksForStudent = new ArrayList<>();
```

the documentation for that is here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Or, alternatively and probably what you want is a hashmap. With the student's name or other unique identifier as the key and then a collection to contain their marks.

```
  HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> gradesForStudents = new HashMap<>();


  gradesForStudents.put("Marc",Arrays.asList("99","98","100"));
```

Something like that.